# Link change in .fla

Tags: flash, hyperlink

Sorry this bad question but i must ask.

I've got a flash site (I don't created) 1 area linked to another site and want to change this link. But i don't found it. Click that area and open ActionScript file, but not found.

How can i change this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided not enough information.

My initial advise would be to use the `Movie Explorer` (top menu -> Window -> Movie Explorer). You'll find there a search field, type the URL (the one you want to change from) and see if it gives you any results.

For more detailed advise we would need to know at least:

1. is this AS2 or AS3
2. do you have any additional .as files
3. the clickable 'area' is a text, image/animation or button?